# Updating a reference variable

Tags: arrays, angularjs

i'm pretty new to angular and javascript in general, and i'm stuck in what might be a simple problem.
Basically, I have a controller which holds some variables

```
(function ()
{
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.project')
    .controller('ProjectController', ProjectController);

/** @ngInject */
function ProjectController($document, $mdDialog, $mdSidenav, Tasks, Tags, DashboardData)
{


    // Methods

var vm = this;
    vm.projects=[
      {name: 'proj1'},
      {name: 'proj2'},
      {name: 'proj3'}
    ];
    vm.selectedProject = vm.projects[0];
....
```

The 2 variables of interest are the array projects and the reference selectedProject.

In my application, i use a service to open a modal, which allows the user to delete the project from the array. The problem is I cannot find a way to update selectedProject if the selected project is removed from the array. As far as I understand, after i remove the object from the array inside the service code, selectedProject still holds the reference to that object.

I tried several approaches in the last couple of days, and now I'm trying to use watch() on the length of the array, so that when it changes i can change the value "pointed" by selectedProject. I still dont have a working solution, but checking around it looks like watch() is quite taxing from a performance point of view.

I'd like an opinion if this could be a proper solution or i should try to find another more efficient.

Comment: You may want to update your question to include the code that is failing to have the desired effect.  It is not clear exactly what you are trying to do or how you are trying to accomplish it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

updating `$scope.selected` could be done with a watch listener, you'd need to make sure your service is updating the projects variable inside your scope so changes will be picked up.

```
$scope.$watch('projects', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue != oldValue && $scope.projects.length) {
    $scope.selected = $scope.projects[0];
  }
}, true);
```

**UPDATE**

If your controller was written in **Controller as** syntax you will want to supply a watchExpression function to your $watch.  Note you will need to bind the controller's value for `this` to the watchExpression function to access the variable you want to watch:

```
// $watch with Controller as syntax
$scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function() {
  return this.projects;
}), function(newValue, oldValue) {
  // newValue is the changed value
});
```

Comment: Paul his answer is correct. However, to be complete, OP is using "controller as" and has put the 'this' reference into a parameter. Therefor, in your answer, change almost all the '$scope' references to 'vm' except for the $scope.$watch. Also, the 'watch' statement should begin as following: $scope.$watch('vm.projects', .....);